# Dynamic website local hosted and implemetned on an Android device

Tags: javascript, android, html, mobile, mobile-development

I have a problem. I have a dynamic website that performs calculations using JavaScript and displays them on an HTML page with the help of PHP, and it also saves the results. I want to make this accessible to my friend as well. However, I don't have the option to host it externally. Now, I've been thinking I could host this website on an Android device and then implement it using WebView. Is there a solution for how this could work?

I have tried to build it with https://github.com/memorex386/Android-WebView-LocalWebServer, but it doesn’t work. Why?

Comment: Small question: why don't you have the option to host it somewhere?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It was weird with two ***completely different*** writing styles in this question: The first part had perfect spelling and grammar, and the second part certainly didn't. Is there an explanation? E.g., was [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) (or similar) used to generate part of this question?